# oracle invalid username/password after changing Visual Studio Servers from VS Development Server to Local IIS Web Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, iis, webserver, database-connection

My code ran normally if In the properties of the project, 
I "Use Visual Studio Development Server",
 but after I switch to use local IIS Web Server,
It always throws "Invalid Username/Password" although I am using my windows credentials.
 My windows credentials have the permission as I can log into local PL/SQL.

my syntax for configuration string is `<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=DBNAME;User ID=/;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>` It should be in correct syntax from here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/windows-authentication/

Help please. Is it a problem of the local IIS? How should I deal with it please? thanks a lot.
Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My supervisor rocks!
He helped fixed the problem. In my case, it's because the Virtual Machine is still using the previous collegue's settings, so I changed the URL to actualmachinename/appname, and make sure my site is using the correct application pool, and then restarted the application tool (control panel->administrative tools --> IIS)